# javascript : convert a string into time

Tags: javascript, html, time

I want to put a string in an input type "time" in my code html

```
<label class="item item-input">
              <span class="input-label">Heure de départ </span>
              <input type="time" ng-model="heureDepart" id="time"  >
</label>
```

when I put it directly , it shows me this error :

```
Error: [ngModel:datefmt] Expected `05:01:01` to be a date
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/ngModel/datefmt?p0=05%3A01%3A01
    at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (ionic.bundle.js:8890)
    at Array.<anonymous> (ionic.bundle.js:28634)
    at Object.ngModelWatch (ionic.bundle.js:32116)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (ionic.bundle.js:23062)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:23333)
    at HTMLBodyElement.<anonymous> (ionic.bundle.js:20191)
    at HTMLBodyElement.eventHandler (ionic.bundle.js:11841)
    at triggerMouseEvent (ionic.bundle.js:2865)
    at tapClick (ionic.bundle.js:2854)
    at HTMLDocument.tapMouseUp (ionic.bundle.js:2927)(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:20434$get @ ionic.bundle.js:17384$get.Scope.$digest @ ionic.bundle.js:23088$get.Scope.$apply @ ionic.bundle.js:23333(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:20191eventHandler @ ionic.bundle.js:11841triggerMouseEvent @ ionic.bundle.js:2865tapClick @ ionic.bundle.js:2854tapMouseUp @ ionic.bundle.js:2927
livereload.js?snipver=1:191 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:35729/livereload' failed: WebSocket opening handshake timed out
```

how can I do it ??

Comment: Can you show what is format of `heureDepart`, just write what is contains

Comment: @evc ..  05:01:01 I got it from database ( column type TIME )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved

I added this inside my controller :

```
 var heure=$state.params.heure+"";
    var h=heure.substring(0, 2);
    var m=heure.substring(3, 5);
    var s=heure.substring(6, 9);
    $scope.heureDepart = { value: new Date(1970, 0, 1, h, m, s ) };
```

and this `ng-model="heureDepart.value"` to my ng-model

Answer (score 0):

tested in jquery and this is the browser message:

> The specified value 'hello' does not conform to the required format. 
>   The format is 'HH:mm', 'HH:mm:ss' or 'HH:mm:ss.SSS' where HH is 00-23,
>   mm is 00-59, ss is 00-59, and SSS is 000-999

you can use only strings with these formats.

change your ng-model to heureDepart.value then inside the controller do

```
$scope.heureDepart = { value: new Date(1970, 0, 1, 05, 01, 01) };
```

and finally we go that!!

Comment: no , I want to convert string to time object not a date !! .. @Vanojx1

Comment: I did the same thing but they show me this error : Error: [ngModel:datefmt] Expected `09:07` to be a date

Comment: ve you also added the placeholder??

Comment: yes I added the placeholder , still the same error !

Comment: change your ng-model to heureDepart.value then inside the controller do $scope.heureDepart = { value: new Date(1970, 0, 1, 05, 01, 01) };

Comment: yesssss it works thank you .. ( instead of 05 01 01 , I make it dynamic ) .. put this comment as an answer plz

Answer (score -1):

You need to follow the time format. The format is 'HH:mm', 'HH:mm:ss' or 'HH:mm:ss.SSS' where HH is 00-23, mm is 00-59, ss is 00-59, and SSS is 000-999.

So, if I wanted to set it to 10:23:24 PM I would do with jQuery:

```
$('#time').val('22:23:24');
```

Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/peteTalksWeb/pen/GpKRKm)

Comment: how can I do it without jQuery just JavaScript ??

Comment: document.getElementById('time').value = '23:24:25';

Comment: did you set the angular model variable to the string?

Comment: I didn't understand .. I added just  document.getElementById('time').value = $state.params.heure;  in my controller

Comment: do you have multiple elements with id "time"?